# How to Edit GPS Location in a Rooted Android 7.1 Phone

Tags: android, gps, android-gps, rooted-device

I searched many solutions from web, like: using Magisk, using Xposed, FakeGPS, etc.

What I have tried is:

1. For FakeGPS, I install it as system app, enable developer mode and choose it as the GPU location provider. Result: no working, other apps still go through WIFI/GPS provider.
2. For Magisk, it requires installation through TWRP, but I am not allowed to rewrite recovery partition of my android phone. All I have is `su` command to get root access for system partition.

Any other solution that helps? I don't care how basic functionality the solution can support, as long as it really works for my case. I even accept the solution to dis-asm the critical library, change the value of Longitude/Latitude to **hardcode** values, re-compile and overwrite the corresponding library.

Answer (score 0):

Mock GPS is an app you can you use with or without root.